# Cannot assign requested address on Blazor Docker with SignalR Hub

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, blazor, signalr

I used the default Blazor Server template to create a Blazor app running in a Docker container.
Everything worked fine until i added a SignalR Hub. I did all steps described in this Microsoft Tutorial. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server
/counter and /fetchdata are working normal in a container but /index produces the following error output: (When starting not in a container everything works fine)

The Docker Log:

`enter code here`https://pastebin.com/aE6wHQ6d

Comment: The answer in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60408442/how-to-run-startasync-connection-of-signalr-blazor-client-in-docker-image
helped me.